# Importing imagery from Google Cloud Buckets to Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-cloud

I have several images stored in a Google Cloud bucket that I would like to import into Google Earth Engine. In the GEE documentation, I can see that Earth Engine can ingest single images from a Bucket using `ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF()` but I have too many images for this to be feasible.

Is there some way import all images in a Bucket as an imageCollection, or to loop through all possible names for images to and add them one-by-one to an imageCollection?

Would it be faster to just download from the bucket and separately upload to Earth Engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add them to a collection, but only by calling the createAsset endpoint yourself.  https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/Earth_Engine_asset_from_cloud_geotiff

Answer (score 2):

Six years later and Noel's answer is still true. See this link for an example:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_creating

```
// All the GeoTiffs are in this folder.
var uriBase = 'gs://gcp-public-data-landsat/LC08/01/001/002/' +
    'LC08_L1GT_001002_20160817_20170322_01_T2/';

// List of URIs, one for each band.
var uris = ee.List([
  uriBase + 'LC08_L1GT_001002_20160817_20170322_01_T2_B2.TIF',
  uriBase + 'LC08_L1GT_001002_20160817_20170322_01_T2_B3.TIF',
  uriBase + 'LC08_L1GT_001002_20160817_20170322_01_T2_B4.TIF',
  uriBase + 'LC08_L1GT_001002_20160817_20170322_01_T2_B5.TIF',
]);

// Make a collection from the list of images.
var images = uris.map(ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF);
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(images);

// Get an RGB image from the collection of bands.
var rgb = collection.toBands().rename(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5']);
Map.centerObject(rgb);
Map.addLayer(rgb, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 20000}, 'rgb');
```

Comment: Tested that in Python I sometimes need to do `images = uris.map(lambda uri: ee.Image.loadGeoTIFF(uri))` to get rid of the error of `AttributeError: 'ApiFunction' object has no attribute 'name'`.